# Display web site logo on address bar 

Tags: html

How can I display my web site logo on the address bar?

Answer (score 3):

You can put these inside `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Make sure that you specify the correct path, usually the root folder.

**[More Info about Favicons](http://www.quotes.co.uk/metatags.php)**

Comment: favicon.ico is hardcored or it be imgname.ico??

Comment: It should be like `favicon.ico`

Answer (score 3):

you just need the favicon.ico in your webroot. the browsers will pick it up automatically.

Using the suggested

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

allows to use differently named icons or different icons for certain pages.

Comment: favicon.ico is hardcored or it be imgname.ico??

Comment: with the html header fields you can select every icon filename you like. favicon.ico in the webroot is just the default.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Answer (score 0):

use a fave icon

```
<head>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.your-page-name.com/favicon.ico"> 
</head>
```